# Require a ruby gem (eventmachine) in a shared server environment

Tags: ruby, hosting, rubygems, shared-hosting, require

I installed the eventmachine rubygem with 'gem install eventmachine' and confirmed its installed by running gem list --local and it shows up. I ran setup.rb in the eventmachine directory as well.

The following code

```
$:.push("/home2/sthoma5/ruby/gems")  // this was in the shared server docs

require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

module EchoServer  
   def receive_data(data)
     send_data(data)
   end
end

EventMachine::run do
   host = "0.0.0.0"
   port = 80
   EventMachine::start_server host, port, EchoServer
   puts "Started EchoServer on #{host}:#{port}"
end
```

Returns the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_requi 
re': no such file to load -- eventmachine (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'                                               
from echo.rb:4
```

It seems I need to require this in a non-standard way because I am on a shared server and don't have access to certain ruby paths? Via SSH I can however navigate to /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.

My eventmachine directory is under home2/sthoma5/ruby/gems/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Ruby are you running?

In Ruby 1.8.x, you need to `require 'rubygems'` first.

Comment: Oh yeah. I actually tried that originally too, but it still errors out. See above. Ruby version is 1.8.7 btw.